# ElasticSearch and Groovy scripting with "\n"

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have next query :

```
{
 "script": " for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.sample.size(); i++) {boolean f = false;if (ctx._source.sample[j].id == sample.id) {ctx._source.sample[j].c_rg = sample.c_rg;f=true;break;}}\nif(!f){ctx._source.sample.add(sample);}}",
 "params": {
   "sample": 
     {
       "id": "GM033438",
       "c_rg": [{"start":"69082","end":"70000"}]
     }

 }

}
```

I have this error :

"type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "failed to compile groovy script",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "multiple_compilation_errors_exception",
                    "reason": "startup failed:\n1dfd396b94db7321e5b5c14fbb1bfc21983608e6: 2: expecting EOF, found '}' @ line 2, column 40.\n   if(!f){ctx._source.sample.add(sample);}}\n                                          ^\n\n1 error\n"
                }

seems that I have a problem with "\n" ... but I have no idea about solve it... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states: `expecting EOF, found '}'`

At this place:

```
if(!f){ctx._source.sample.add(sample);}}
```

(last `}` is not needed)

Comment: You realize that this is not how SO is supposed to function?